# What would be time complexity of the below basic code

Tags: python, time-complexity

Can some help me understand the time complexity of the basic Leet code problem I solved

```
class Solution:
def numUniqueEmails(self, emails: List[str]) -> int:
    new_list=[]
    for i in emails:
            if '.' in i.split('@')[0] or '+' in i.split('@')[0]:
                k=(i.split('@')[0].replace('.','')).split('+')[0]
                #print(k)
                new_list.append(k+'@'+(i.split('@')[1]))
                print(new_list)
            else:
                new_list.append(i)
    return len(set(new_list))
```

Comment: The question is getting downvoted (not by me) probably because it seems like you didn't do enough research. If you can write the code above then you should be able to understand basic time complexity.  You are looping through a list, what time complexity is that? Use Google and YouTube to learn about time complexity for a few minutes and if you're still lost after I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Because `split()` looks at each character in the string `i`, and this is done in a loop over each `i` in `emails`, the time complexity is O(n) where n is the total number of characters in all `emails` combined.

The `split()` method also creates copies of substrings of `i`, such that in aggregate the work done by `split()` may be double that indicated above. The code also appends either `i` or a modified version of `i` to `new_list`, which could involve creating new strings totaling up to `n` characters and creating an array with length matching `emails`. These considerations do not change the overall analysis, with time complexity O(n).